# Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: Cannot read property 'addService' of null

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, adsense, adsense-api

I am using adsesne code in my angularjs application. On the first load of application ads are working fine when I switch content dynamically I get this error.

`Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: Cannot read property 'addService' of null site:stackoverflow.com`.

This is the script which I load inside my div.

```
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
  window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/28379801/MWBanner320x50', [320, 50], 'div-adlocation').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
<!-- /28379801/MWBanner320x50 -->
<div id='div-adlocation' style='width: 320px; height: 50px; margin:auto'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-adlocation'); });
  </script>
</div>
```

Any possible work around using angularjs?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and saw your post. Only after two weeks I found out by accident that you get the same error if you define the slot twice with the same `adUnitPath`. Maybe you have the same issue.

**Solution**

Make sure that the `adUnitPath` is define only once. The easiest way to check this for me was to `console.log(<the adUnitPath>)` with every `googletag.defineSlot(...)` call. In the screenshot you can see that two attempts are made to definer the same slot. However, this is not possible because the adUnitPath must be unique.

[Example of the error and the double define action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxGDL.png)

Comment: Yes, I did'not know, but I have registered two unitpath with the same same